# How to set up browser environment variables in nextjs when `"type": "module"`?

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables

I am working on a nextjs project and I am not being able to set environment variables that work and browser level.

`console.log(process.env)` always returns `{}` in the javascript console and any variable `process.env.<variable>` has an `undefined` value.

I've been reading the documentation about how to setup env variables [using next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/env) and [.env](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) file with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix. None if these alternatives are working in my case. Most (if not all) the info that I found I think does not apply in my case because I am using `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --require @babel/register --require ignore-styles",
    "run": "--require @babel/register --require ignore-styles"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ....
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.21.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.21.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
    ...
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

My `next.config.js` file is the following:

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    custom_key: 'test1234',
    TEST: 'asd!!'

  },
  pageExtensions: ['mdx', 'md', 'jsx', 'js', 'tsx', 'ts'],
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      }
    );
    config.resolve.extensions = ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', ...config.resolve.extensions]
    return config;
  }
};

export default nextConfig;
```

and when I call `process.env.custom_key` or `process.env.TEST` I always get undefined.

I also tried defining these variables (for example `NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST`) in the `.env` and/or `.env.local` file and in that case when I always get `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST = undefined`.

Everywhere I see that the fix is using

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    customKey: 'my-value',
  },
};
```

but since I am using `"type": "module"` I can't use this. So my question is, what I am missing here? Is my nextConfig wrong defined? What I am missing here so I can use environment variables at browser level.

At server level, process.env seems to work because it is printing everything that I have in my `.env` and `env.local` files. But not what I have in the `next.config.js` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after upgrading nextjs `13.1.6 -> 13.4.0` the problem is fixed.

Now I can setup env variables with the prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in my `.env.local` and everything is working as expected.